# Access first and last elements in nested lists

Tags: python, pandas, list

My DataFrame contains nested lists. I want to keep the first and last elements in the sublists and then flaten the lists. e.g.:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'names':[[['harry','james','potter'],['Albus','Dumbledore']],[['Peter','D.','Griffin'],['some','nice','string']]]})
df
```

and the output should look like this

```
0  ['Harry Potter','Albus Dumbledore']
1  ['Peter Griffin','some string']
```

Since i am new to paython i am a bit overchallenged with the double loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can even do it after creating the data frame :

```
df['names'] = df.names.apply(lambda x: [ ' '.join([i[0],i[-1]]) for i in x] )
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this one line:-

```
df1["names"] = [[j[0] + " " + j[-1]  for j in i] for i in df1["names"]]
```

Output

```
                              names
0  [harry potter, Albus Dumbledore]
1      [Peter Griffin, some string]
```